# Using YUM for CentALT packages

Tags: centos, yum, mariadb

Since CentALT isn't available anymore I can't upgrade some of my packages. Sure I can use a mirror for CentALT to get it working, but it only lists 'older' packages since it's not updated anymore. I installed MariaDB 10.0.11 with CentALT and would like to update it to 10.0.12. Unfortunately this results in an error with a RPM of the MariaDB repo.

Is there a way to update it without removing the current package?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience when dealing with switching from one repo to another for a given package, it's almost always easier to back the current repo's installation of that package out and then do a install of the package using the new repo.

It usually leads to all sorts of problems which are way more work then to just deal with the uninstall/re-install step.

**NOTE:** I would suggest collecting any of the relevant files that pertain to the current install prior to attempting this. For example if it's a database I would make a directory where I'd keep copies of any of the files under `/etc` or `/var`, for example`, and keep the files there for reference as you re-setup the new package from the new repo.

Answer (score 0):

```
CentALT BEWARE:
CentALT has returned after three (3) months of death, BUT.
admittedly, CentALT has had some of the fastest RHEL-type rpm issuances in the past. unfortunately, since no news or reasoning for CentALT's temporary demise exists and due to CentALT's russian location there certainly is a high potential for russian governmental intrusion. thus, i am not tempted to return to using CentALT.

a good set of alternatives to CentALT -- with stellar reputations and prompt updating -- are the PUIAS repo's operated by princeton univ, NJ, USA (a premier engineering school). you can start here:
http://springdale.math.ias.edu/wiki/YumRepositories6


the breadth of coverage by PUIAS repo's v. CentALT is comparable, although princeton puts the rpm's into several classes. just download the files for the various classes and combine them into a single, unified repo file and you will be good to go!
```

Comment: If this is a quote, you should cite or link to where it is from.